# Android Eclipse device configuration not showing connected Device

Tags: android, configuration

I am configuring my android device v 2.3.6 Ginger Bread with eclipse. In devices panel my device is visible. But when I turn to Run Configuration and try to select devices, my device is not showing up in the panel as it says to select with a device with minimum API level 14. How can I select my device having API 10 to work with?[image]

Answer (score 1):

You must specify your SDK version (which is API level) in AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

Comment: ... and also install a compatible USB bridge device driver.

Comment: I am using these settings is it ok to go with <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you opening a commandprompt, navigating to `<your eclipse folder>\sdk\platform-tools\` and then try to run `adb devices` , this will start daemon if it is not running. This must list your device if it is connected, and a right driver is installed

Comment: This should be an edit to your previous answer, Not a different one.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:** 
found my answer after a long search. thanks
http://www.cannonade.net/blog.php?id=1585
Cleaned the project and rebuilt. It's now displaying my device. thanks to all the folks for reply.